# Laravel Eloquent - model relationship with pivot table

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, many-to-many

I can't really find a relationship solution for these models.

1. Bus has multiple destinations
2. Destination has multiple buses
3. Term has one bus and one destination

**Bus**

- id
- number

**Destination**

- name

**Term**

- date
- price

---

If bus had only one destination then I have this and I think it should work.

BUS MODEL

```
public function destinations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Destination');
}

public function terms()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Term', 'App\Destination');
}
```

DESTINATION MODEL

```
public function boats()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Boat');
}

public function terms()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Term');
}
```

TERM MODEL

```
public function destination()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('WBZ\Destination');
}
```

---

What I want to be able to achieve:

```
Bus::find(1)->destinations()->get();
Bus::find(1)->terms()->get();
```

Comment: How are these models related? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: @devk 1) Bus has multiple destinations 2) Destination has multiple buses 3) Term has one bus and one destination

Answer (score 1):

BUS MODEL.

```
public function destinations()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Destination');
}

public function term()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Term');
}
```

DESTINATION MODEL

```
public function term()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Term');
}

public function buses()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Bus');
}
```

Term Model.

```
public function destination()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Destination');
}
public function bus()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Bus');
}
```